# Clojure fails when calling amap on a primitive array

Tags: java, arrays, clojure, functional-programming, interop

On ClojureDocs, it mentions that aset is only workable on array of refrence java types. But it does not mentions about the usage of amap.

```
(reduce
  (fn [#^doubles sum #^doubles prob]
    (println sum)
    (amap ^doubles sum idx ret 
      (fn [x] (println x) (+ x (get prob idx)))))
  (double-array 3 (double 0))
  [(double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])])
```

Above code fails with below error message

> IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: aset 
>   clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)

It seems that amap could not be used in this scenario.

I have two questions:

- Is there any neat solution to return a primitive array for a simple map logic?
- why aset is not supported for primitive array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `amap` incorrectly. The last param to amap should be an expression and not a function (like normal map) as you have used.

```
(reduce
  (fn [^doubles sum ^doubles prob]
    (println sum)
    (amap ^doubles sum idx ret 
      (+ (aget sum idx) (aget prob idx))))
  (double-array 3 (double 0))
  [(double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
   (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])])
```

Comment: Thanks, Ankur, it is my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

If array has small number of elements you can just use `map`:

```
(apply map + [(double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
              (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
              (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
              (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])
              (double-array [1.0 2.0 3.0])])

=> (5.0 10.0 15.0)
```

It looks cleaner. And you can transform the final result of computation to array by `into-array` if you really need it.